# Adding number to date not working

Tags: php, custom-field, user-meta, date

I am adding number stored in custom user meta data to current date.
Here is my code

```
$addeddays = get_user_meta($this->order->user_id, 'xxx', true);
$timeBase = date('j.n.Y');
echo date('j.n.Y', strtotime($timeBase, "+ $addeddays days"));
```

But output is 1.1.1970

What is wrong in code or how to do it with other method?
I read question about this but in answers was also my method so I do not know why it is not working.

Comment: this is actually a php question, not wordpress.  You would get more answers by putting in a different forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is not working, because you use `strtotime` incorrectly... It should be used like this:

```
int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now ] )
```

But you pass formatted dated as first param, and another string as second one.

So how should it look like? Like so:

```
$addeddays = intval( get_user_meta($this->order->user_id, 'xxx', true) );
$timeBase = date('Y-m-d');
echo date('j.n.Y', strtotime( "+ {$addeddays} days", strtotime( $timeBase ) ));
```

Or a simpler version (since `$timeBase is today:

```
$addeddays = intval( get_user_meta($this->order->user_id, 'xxx', true) );
echo date( 'j.n.Y', strtotime( "+ {$addeddays} days" ) );
```

Comment: This is working right. Thanks for answer. It helped me understand these date functions.